# Can QSys recurse through custom component, to generate IP?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus, qsys

I have a custom QSys component, that instantiates a couple of Altera IP. The Altera IP is also in the form of .qsys files. Is it possible to have Qsys recurse through my custom component and generate the instantiated IP for me? Currently I have to open each IP separately and generate it, only then does the component synthesize properly?

Comment: I am using Quartus Prime Pro, which instantiates regular IP as `.qsys` components (FIFOs, RAM etc). This IP which is part of my custom component is not generated as part of the over all QSys system. Currently I get around this by listing the QSys generated files for the instance in the dependency for my custom component and not the actual IP file (i.e `.qsys` file)

Answer (score 1):

Qsys distinguishes between **components** (defined by a `.tcl` file), and **subsystems** (defined by a `.qsys` file). It looks like you want to use subsystems.

The procedure for adding either of them is basically the same though. Add the path where you store the components or subsystems to the `IP search path` in Qsys preferences. After you refresh the system those components and/or subsystems should appear in the component list, and you can instantiate them like with the built-in components. Subsystems should show up in the `Project -> System` group in the component tree. When you generate the system, the subsystems will be generated as well.

While this is how it's *supposed* to work, there are various bugs in different Quartus versions that can give you some problems. The easiest and safest way is to keep all the `.qsys` files (both the top system and the subsystems) in the directory of your Quartus project, and launch Qsys from Quartus when your project is already open.